# Replace values in a matrix with NAs if the row/column names appear in a list

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with matching row and column names. I also have a list with some of the row/column names. In the matrix, I want to replace all cells of the rows and columns with the names NOT included in the list with NAs.

Here is the matrix:

```
> A <- matrix(c(2,0,3,0,5,NA,1,0,NA,6,11,9,0,1,NA,2,0,1,NA,3,6,1,NA,0,0), nrow=5, ncol=5) 
> dimnames(A) = list(c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"),  c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"))
> A
    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
ID1   2  NA  11   2   6
ID2   0   1   9   0   1
ID3   3   0   0   1  NA
ID4   0  NA   1  NA   0
ID5   5   6  NA   3   0
```

The list could look like this:

```
  B<-list("ID1","ID2","ID5")
[[1]]
[1] "ID1"

[[2]]
[1] "ID2"

[[3]]
[1] "ID5"
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
ID1   2  NA  NA  NA  6
ID2   0   1  NA  NA   1
ID3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
ID4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
ID5   5   6  NA  NA   0
```

I have tried the following:

```
C <- A[A != B,A != B]<- NA
C <- A[(!(A[B,B]))]<- NA
```

...and some versions of it, but I'm obviously doing something wrong...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can generate `rownames` and `colnames` of the matrix using `row` and `col` and change them to `NA` which do not match the names in `B`.

```
A[!(rownames(A)[row(A)] %in% unlist(B) & colnames(A)[col(A)] %in% unlist(B))] <- NA

A
#    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
#ID1   2  NA  NA  NA   6
#ID2   0   1  NA  NA   1
#ID3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#ID4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#ID5   5   6  NA  NA   0
```

---

Or since you have a matrix with matching row and column names a more easy to understand approach would be to first find out the row/column names that we want to change to `NA` and then change them to `NA` sequentially.

```
vals <- setdiff(rownames(A), unlist(B)) 
A[vals, ] <- NA     #Turn rows to NA
A[, vals] <- NA     #Turn columns to NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
v1 <- unlist(B)
melt(A) %>%
   mutate(value = replace(value, !((Var1  %in% v1) & 
                                   (Var2 %in% v1)), NA)) %>% 
   spread(Var2, value) %>%
   column_to_rownames('Var1')
#     ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
#ID1   2  NA  NA  NA   6
#ID2   0   1  NA  NA   1
#ID3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#ID4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#ID5   5   6  NA  NA   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the rows to NA and then the columns to NA.  No packages are used.

```
A[!rownames(A) %in% unlist(B), ] <- NA
A[, !colnames(A) %in% unlist(B)] <- NA
```